Error Connecting to rubygems.org During bundle install with JRuby on ARM64
Question:
I'm encountering an issue while running bundle install with JRuby on an ARM64 architecture. Here are the details:

JRuby version: jruby-9.3.10.0 [arm64]
Bundler version: 2.4.22

When I attempt to run bundle install, I receive the following error:
Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

To troubleshoot, I tried installing the specific Bundler version required by my application:
gem install bundler -v 2.2.17

But I get this error:
you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or, if there is a Jars.lock file, resolve the jars with the `lock_jars` command
no such file to load -- org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml-engine/2.7/snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar (LoadError)

I tested my connection to rubygems.org using the following curl command:
curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby

Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:
Ruby:           2.6.8p0 (2023-02-01 revision 67951) [java]
RubyGems:       3.2.33
Bundler:        2.4.22
Compiled with:  JRuby-OpenSSL 0.15.0
Loaded version: JRuby-OpenSSL 0.15.0
SSL_CERT_FILE:  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
SSL_CERT_DIR:   /etc/ssl/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...
Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       failed  ❌  (
you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` command

no such file to load -- org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml-engine/2.7/snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar (LoadError))
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      failed  ❌  (
    you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` command

no such file to load -- org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml-engine/2.7/snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar (LoadError))

Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: success ✅
It looks like Ruby and Bundler can connect to rubygems.org, but RubyGems itself cannot. You can likely solve this by manually downloading and installing a RubyGems update. Visit http://ruby.to/ssl-check-failed for instructions on how to manually upgrade RubyGems. 
I've tried everything, including resolving the lock_jars issue by downloading the snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar and placing it in the correct file path. I've also opened an issue with JRuby https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1302#issuecomment-2255047736.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide any additional information if needed.
I expect my macbook to use jruby and establish connection to RubyGems.org so I can use bundler and other functions. I think it's a problem with the way the java permissions are set up.
Per @engineersmnky comment, Thanks for looking into my post.
gem install psych
=>
RuntimeError: 

    you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` command

no such file to load -- org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml-engine/2.7/snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar (LoadError)
              do_require at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:356
             require_jar at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:265
  require_jar_with_block at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:307
             require_jar at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:264
             require_jar at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:363
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych_jars.rb:5
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017
        require_relative at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych.rb:5
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017
                 require at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85
               load_yaml at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:624
               load_file at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:346
              initialize at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:189
                     new at org/jruby/RubyClass.java:890
        do_configuration at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73
                     run at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:38
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin/jgem:21
                    load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin/gem:4
LoadError: no such file to load -- org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml-engine/2.7/snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017
                 require at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85
              do_require at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:353
             require_jar at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:265
  require_jar_with_block at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:307
             require_jar at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:264
             require_jar at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:363
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych_jars.rb:5
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017
        require_relative at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych.rb:5
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017
                 require at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85
               load_yaml at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:624
               load_file at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:346
              initialize at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:189
                     new at org/jruby/RubyClass.java:890
        do_configuration at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:73
                     run at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:38
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin/jgem:21
                    load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052
                  <main> at /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin/gem:4

bundle install
=>--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError: 

    you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` command

no such file to load -- org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml-engine/2.7/snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar (LoadError)
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:356:in `do_require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:265:in `block in require_jar'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:307:in `require_jar_with_block'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:264:in `require_jar'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:363:in `require_jar'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych_jars.rb:5:in `<main>'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017:in `require'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045:in `require_relative'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych.rb:5:in `<main>'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017:in `require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:624:in `load_yaml'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:189:in `initialize'
  org/jruby/RubyClass.java:890:in `new'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:344:in `configuration'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:255:in `connection'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:101:in `initialize'
  org/jruby/RubyClass.java:890:in `new'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:259:in `block in fetchers'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2667:in `map'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:257:in `fetchers'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:402:in `block in remote_specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:401:in `remote_specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:134:in `specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:41:in `block in setup_solver'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:794:in `default'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1265:in `[]'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:240:in `all_versions_for'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:57:in `block in setup_solver'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:794:in `default'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1265:in `[]'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:159:in `versions_for'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:382:in `block in prepare_dependencies'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1519:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:799:in `map'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:377:in `prepare_dependencies'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:61:in `setup_solver'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:28:in `start'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:570:in `start_resolution'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:301:in `resolve'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:523:in `materialize'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:231:in `ensure_specs_are_compatible!'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `block in run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
  org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1148:in `open'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:71:in `run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:23:in `install'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:261:in `block in install'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/settings.rb:142:in `temporary'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:260:in `install'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in `start'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/exe/bundle:37:in `block in <main>'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/exe/bundle:29:in `<main>'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052:in `load'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
LoadError: no such file to load -- org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml-engine/2.7/snakeyaml-engine-2.7.jar
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017:in `require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:353:in `do_require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:265:in `block in require_jar'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:307:in `require_jar_with_block'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:264:in `require_jar'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/jar_dependencies.rb:363:in `require_jar'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych_jars.rb:5:in `<main>'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017:in `require'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1045:in `require_relative'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/psych-5.1.2-java/lib/psych.rb:5:in `<main>'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1017:in `require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:624:in `load_yaml'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/config_file.rb:189:in `initialize'
  org/jruby/RubyClass.java:890:in `new'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:344:in `configuration'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:255:in `connection'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:101:in `initialize'
  org/jruby/RubyClass.java:890:in `new'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:259:in `block in fetchers'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2667:in `map'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:257:in `fetchers'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:402:in `block in remote_specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:401:in `remote_specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:134:in `specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:41:in `block in setup_solver'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:794:in `default'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1265:in `[]'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:240:in `all_versions_for'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:57:in `block in setup_solver'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:794:in `default'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1265:in `[]'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:159:in `versions_for'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:382:in `block in prepare_dependencies'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1519:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:799:in `map'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:377:in `prepare_dependencies'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:61:in `setup_solver'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:28:in `start'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:570:in `start_resolution'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:301:in `resolve'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:523:in `materialize'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `specs'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:231:in `ensure_specs_are_compatible!'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `block in run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
  org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1148:in `open'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:71:in `run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:23:in `install'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:261:in `block in install'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/settings.rb:142:in `temporary'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:260:in `install'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in `start'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/exe/bundle:37:in `block in <main>'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/gems/bundler-2.4.22/exe/bundle:29:in `<main>'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052:in `load'
  /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'


Environment
Bundler             2.4.22
  Platforms         ruby, universal-java-11
Ruby                2.6.8p0 (2023-02-01 revision 67951) [universal-java-11]
  Full Path         /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin/jruby
  Config Dir        /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/etc
RubyGems            3.2.33
  Gem Home          /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0
  Gem Path          /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0:/Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.3.10.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared
  User Home         /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj
  User Path         /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.gem/jruby/2.6.0
  Bin Dir           /Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.3.10.0/bin
OpenSSL             
  Compiled          JRuby-OpenSSL 0.15.0
  Loaded            JRuby-OpenSSL 0.15.0
  Cert File         /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
  Cert Dir          /etc/ssl/certs
Tools               
  Git               2.45.2
  RVM               1.29.12 (latest)
  rbenv             not installed
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)

Bundler Build Metadata
Built At          2023-11-09
Git SHA           ec2089640
Released Version  true

Bundler settings
build.nokogiri
  Set for the current user (/Users/darshanvenkatabhojaraj/.bundle/config): "--use-system-libraries"

Gemfile
Gemfile
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) { |repo_name| "git@github.com:#{repo_name}.git" }

if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  ruby '2.6.8', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '9.3.10.0'
else
  ruby '3.1.2'
end

gem 'activeldap', '~> 6.1.0', require: 'active_ldap/railtie'
gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter'
gem 'config'
gem 'duo_api'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'haml'
gem 'health_check'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'js-routes'
gem 'net-ldap', '~> 0.16.3'
gem 'phony'
gem 'pundit' # Authorization gem
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.5'
gem 'ruby-saml'
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'splunk-sdk-ruby'
gem 'syslogger'
gem 'therubyrhino'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'uglifier'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 2.7'
  gem 'erb_lint', platforms: :mri
  gem 'git'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.90.0', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-performance', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rails', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'amazing_print', require: false
  gem 'bundle-audit', require: false
  gem 'jruby-jars', '9.2.13.0' # This needs to match the specified version above for the war file
  gem 'overcommit', '0.52.1', require: false
  gem 'warbler', require: false, platforms: :jruby
end

group :production do
  gem 'exception_notification'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'geckodriver-helper'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'minitest-rg'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec-retry'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.13'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'
end

Gemfile.lock
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      actionview (= 5.2.6)
      activejob (= 5.2.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.6)
      actionview (= 5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activeldap (6.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.2)
      builder
      gettext
      gettext_i18n_rails
      locale
    activemodel (5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
    activerecord (5.2.6)
      activemodel (= 5.2.6)
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activerecord-nulldb-adapter (0.7.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.2.0, < 6.3)
    activestorage (5.2.6)
      actionpack (= 5.2.6)
      activerecord (= 5.2.6)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
    activesupport (5.2.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    amazing_print (1.3.0)
    archive-zip (0.12.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    better_html (1.0.16)
      actionview (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      ast (~> 2.0)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      html_tokenizer (~> 0.0.6)
      parser (>= 2.4)
      smart_properties
    builder (3.2.4)
    bundle-audit (0.1.0)
      bundler-audit
    bundler-audit (0.8.0)
      bundler (>= 1.2.0, < 3)
      thor (~> 1.0)
 
 
 *** MORE GEMS HERE***
    
  erb_lint
  exception_notification
  faraday
  geckodriver-helper
  git
  haml
  health_check
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  jruby-jars (= 9.2.13.0)
  js-routes
  launchy
  minitest-rg
  net-ldap (~> 0.16.3)
  overcommit (= 0.52.1)
  phony
  pry
  puma
  pundit
  rails (~> 5.2.5)
  rails-controller-testing
  rspec-rails
  rspec-retry
  rspec_junit_formatter
  rubocop (~> 0.90.0)
  rubocop-performance
  rubocop-rails
  rubocop-rspec
  ruby-saml
  sdoc
  selenium-webdriver (~> 3.13)
  shoulda-matchers (~> 4.0)
  splunk-sdk-ruby
  syslogger
  therubyrhino
  timecop
  turbolinks
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier
  warbler
  webdrivers (~> 4.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.7p0 (jruby 9.2.13.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.17

--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------
Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.
First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/search?q=&type=Issues
If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please fill in the new issue form located at https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/new?labels=Bundler&template=bundler-related-issue.md, and copy and paste the report template above in there.

Can you try gem install psych and see what that says? Also the full error for bundle install would probably be very useful.

@engineersmnky - Please see post, I've edited it. Thank you so much.

Have you confirmed that libyaml is installed correctly as well? Have you tried removing and then reinstalling the ruby version? Also I noticed the ruby version in the Gemfile does not match the one that created the Gemfile.lock, while unlikely to be an issue try removing the lockfile and running bundle install again. (just running through debugging options)
